# Ant pattern matcher starting with and having decimal values

Tags: regex, ant, pattern-matching

I want to do an ant match for initializing a variable as below."version" is input.
if version is 1.2.X.X then value should be true (X means anything[1-9]) else value should be false

Example :
version = 1.3.0.5, value = false 
version = 1.2.0.5, value = true 
version = 1.2.5.3, value = true
version = 2.1.0.5, value = false

```
<if>
  <matches string="@{VERSION}" pattern="^1.2"/>
  <then>
      <property name="version.value" value="true"/>
  </then>
  <else>
      <property name="version.value" value="false"/>
  </else>
</if>
```

What should be the pattern to check first 2 digit including '.' [1.2.x.x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend avoiding `ant-contrib` tasks whenever possible, as they tend to encourage the use of Ant as a programming language, which will often cause problems down the road as your build script evolves. Ant's native `condition` task is perfectly suited for this situation.

Regarding your pattern, as the The fourth bird already posted, `.` is a special character in regex so it needs to be escaped.

```
<property name="VERSION" value="1.2.0.5" />

<condition property="version.value" else="false">
    <matches string="${VERSION}" pattern="^1\.2" />
</condition>

<echo message="${version.value}" />
```

A couple notes:

- By default, the `condition` task sets the property to "true" if the nested condition evaluates to true, but leaves the property *unset* if it evaluates to false. Normally, this is a useful feature in Ant, but if you really need it to be set to "false" (or any other value), you can use the `else` attribute which I've included.
- The simple pattern `^1\.2` technically works here, but it's not very restrictive. If you want to avoid matching values that start with `1.2` but don't conform specifically to a `1.2.x.x` pattern (e.g. `1.2asdf`, you'll want to use something that checks the whole string, such as `^1\.2\.\d\.\d$`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the dot to match it literally.

For `1.2.0.5` to match you have to include the zero `[0-9]` for the third digit.

Try this pattern:

[`^1\.2\.[0-9]\.[0-9]$`](https://regex101.com/r/E5qvJt/1)